# how to use ajax to change data in blade template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

hey guys i'm trying to make changes in my blade template using ajax , when i press the button it changes the value of data in database and i want to display this data at once on my blade template .
that's my java script code :

```
(function($){
    $('.wishlistForm').on('submit', function(){
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                var wishlistButton = form.find("button[type='submit']");
                var x = parseInt($('.wish-btn-count').text());
                if(response.actiondone == 'added') {
                    $('.wish-btn-count').text(x++);
                    console.log(x);
                    wishlistButton.text(response.message);
                } else if(response.actiondone == 'removed') {
                    $('.wish-btn-count').text(x--);
                    console.log(x);
                    wishlistButton.text(response.message);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and here is the part i want to change in my template :

```
<div class="wish-btn-count" id="wishlist">
                        {{$wishlistcount}}
                    </div>
```

so how can i do it ? and for record it returns the value right in the console but don't show it in my view

Comment: the "java script" code can't manipulate the blade template directly because blade templates are compiled by the php into html

Comment: then how to do it please @madalinivascu

Comment: the code you provided should change the html with your desired number

Comment: exactly but it changes it after reload not when i press the submit button @madalinivascu

Comment: Of course you can manipulate blade template via jquery or javascript. The first tip - if you use post method in laravel then you need to send the csrf_token in ajax data.

Comment: @forexknight it's sent in my form

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default submit event, so you can trigger the ajax

```
 $('.wishlistForm').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work and the error isn't in this part it's in typing the x value in success function

Comment: is your ajax triggering correctly ,what is there turned code for your xhr request?

Comment: yes it is triggered correctly and it adds and removes data correctly but don't show it

Comment: can you provide a sample of the resonse?

Comment: {"actiondone":"removed","message":"Add to wishlist"} that's is the response when it's removed and it's printed right in the console

Answer (score 0):

This may be the solution.

```
If you are receiving json object response from the ajax call,first you have to parse that object and then use it.


Try this,

(function($){
$('.wishlistForm').on('submit', function(){
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
           /*Add this in your code*/
            var response = JSON.parse(response.trim());
            var wishlistButton = form.find("button[type='submit']");
            var x = parseInt($('.wish-btn-count').text());
            if(response.actiondone == 'added') {
                $('.wish-btn-count').text(x++);
                console.log(x);
                wishlistButton.text(response.message);
            } else if(response.actiondone == 'removed') {
                $('.wish-btn-count').text(x--);
                console.log(x);
                wishlistButton.text(response.message);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: response.trim is not a function it gives me that error

Comment: Try it without using trim.
var response=JSON.parse(response);

Comment: After this statement,
var response = JSON.parse(response);
check the value of json object in console. Add this and see the response.
console.log(response.actiondone);
console.log(response.message);

After that check whether it is entering inside the if statements

Comment: still gives me the error : Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Try this,
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));

Comment: still didn't change the icon pro